# Change color of element onMouseOver using javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm writing javascript which will change the color of an element when the mouse hovers over it. I know perfectly how to do this using jQuery, but this time around I *have* to do it using either pure JS or Prototype.

Why doesn't this work:

`<div id="boundary1"></div>`

```
document.getElementById("boundary1").onmouseover(function() {
    alert("test");
})
```

firebug returns:

`TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onmouseover is not a function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you may be thinking a little too 'jQuery', try this:

```
var boundary = document.getElementById('boundary');
var mouseOverFunction = function () {
    // this.style.color = '#000'; // your colour change
};
boundary.onmouseover = mouseOverFunction;
```

I've separated the logic to make the development and logic clearer, it makes your functions reusable too.

Comment: How to make it disappear? Make it temporaryly instead of permanently... Is it possible? The method presented on your answer makes the color stay on mouse hovering forever. Is there any methods available for making it disappear?

Answer (score 1):

The Prototype way to do this would be this:

```
$('elementId').observe('mouseenter', function(evt){
    this.setStyle('background-color: yellow');
}).observe('mouseleave', function(evt){
    this.setStyle('background-color: inherit');
});
```

But as others have already pointed out, the real way to do this is with CSS. The only reason I could imagine needing to do it in JS is if you have to support IE <= 8, which doesn't like to do the :hover pseudo-class on anything except the A tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("boundary1").onmouseover = function() { 
  alert("test");
}
```

[More Info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onmouseover)

Comment: I still have to wait a couple of min. Is there a way to pass the selected element to that function?

Comment: @Ortix92: I didnt get you. Please elaborate your question. What is the selected element? Ans where do you want to pass it to?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<td onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#00CC00'" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#009900'" bgColor=#009900>
<A HREF="#">Click Here</A></TD>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS

```
<style>
.changecolour:hover
{
background-color:yellow;
}
</style>
```

Now for the text you want to change color

```
<span class ="changecolour">Color changes when mouse comes here.</span>
```

Reference : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Where in my question did I mention CSS? I specifically asked about JS and Prototype